# Is it permissible to pray taraweeh at home?

Tags: fiqh, taraweeh

Is it obligatory to pray taraweeh behind imam at mosque. Can we pray taraweeh alone at home ?

Answer (score -1):

It is religiously obligatory to pray Tarawih prayers in congregation in Masjids or mosques

But it is considered a highly praiseworthy act to do so because the worshipper has the opportunity to listen to the recital of the Quran by an expert Quran reader and the worshipper has the opportunity to meet others and share their concerns and ideas and this helps to develop unity, cordiality and better undestanding

Comment: This is simply wrong.